# How to set up Jeash for Haxe?

Tags: terminal, haxe, fdt

I am trying to setup Jeash for Haxe, so I read this: http://old.haxe.org/com/libs/jeash/firststeps

Now, I found out that I cannot do that just yet:

> "This is the first time you are runing haxelib. Please run haxelib setup first"

(and I love the typo in there :P )

So I decided to read this: http://haxe.org/com/haxelib/setup

I tried what is suggested. First command, I get prompted for a password, so I enter what is necessary when I install software on my comp.

Then I ran "sudo chown jansensan -R /usr/lib/haxe" (replacing "myusername" with my actual username, "jansensan") and then I get an error: "chown: -R: No such file or directory"

Is there a way to get a little bit more information? I mean, the explanation on the Haxe website makes it sound as it if will magically happen, and it is not the case.

For anyone interested (if it helps you understand my issue), my computer is a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard and I intend to code in FDT. BTW, I can already do some Haxe stuff in FDT, why would I need to run the Haxe setup to be able to install Jeash and NME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these suggestions are quite good. An alternative to dealing with all this Terminal writing is to go to http://www.haxenme.org/developers/get-started/ and use the installers provided. Afterwards, go in the prefs of FDT > Haxe SDK and add the path where the haxelib was installed, "/usr/lib/haxe" most likely.

Answer (score 1):

haxelib is a lib repositories .It adds libs to your workflow. jeash and NME are one of them.
once you have installed haxe. you just have to run in the terminal haxelib setup.Normally it goes fine. 
I'm on macpro snow leopard too.Never had issues with that !.
test haxelib on terminal .. wath does it tell ?

Comment: The errors I got were in my original post, the Terminal commands would not work as expected.

Overall, I ended up using the installers found on http://www.haxenme.org/developers/get-started, as it was suggested to me by Twitter user @singmajesty

Answer (score 1):

You're using FDT and no other Haxe installation right? This is important because FDT comes with it's own 'installation' of Haxe.

You have it two ways:

1. Add it to Haxelib.
2. Just download the source code and put the jeash library in the
   project your using.

### **Add it to Haxelib.**

For command line: you're going to need to make haxelib visible to your command line.

Get started by typing 'which haxelib'. This will tell you

1) if you have haxelib via command line. 
2) Where it is.

[image]

If there is an error, then it's not visible to your command line. This is ok, you'll just need to add the whole path when calling it. Like this:

[image]

Also notice that since FDT 5 is shipped as an OSX bundle you'll have to go 'inside' of it via right click FDT -> 'Show Contents'.

When you have this path (or if you are using your own version of the haXe SDK ), you can use it to call haxelib.

[image]

### **Add it to source path**

Download the library source code and physically add it to your source path.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for these details! However, as I answered to postite, I ended up using the installets from haxenme.org/developers/get-started, it worked like a charm! I just had to point in FDT where the new haxelib was located, and all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the NME installer:

http://www.haxenme.org

It will install Haxe, Neko, HXCPP, NME and Jeash in one go. NME supports Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS, webOS, Flash and HTML5 -- the HTML5 target handled using Jeash.